# Cannot Import on Worker Script with Webpack 5 & worker-plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, web-worker

I'm having some trouble figuring out how I can get imports working on a worker script.

I have this React Component:

```
export function MyComponent({...}: propType) {
 const worker = useMemo(
    () => new Worker(new URL('../../../workers/worker.js', import.meta.url), {type: "module"}),
    [],
  );
  ...
}
```

and my worker.js

```
import { x } from 'someModule';

self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log('Starting worker');

  const n = await x.generate(3072);
  self.postMessage(n);
});
```

and finally my webpack.config.js:

```
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin');
...
module.exports = {
   plugins = [ new WorkerPlugin(), ...]
}
```

with the above configuration I'm getting `Module parse failed: ParserHelpers.addParsedVariableToModule is not a function` when trying to run my app. What should I change with regards to my webpack configuration and or worker script?